# Program for Bot that is deployed on Replit's Reserved VM server is not executing on time

Tags: python, time, schedule, replit, praw

I'm trying to deploy a python program on replit, The problem is that after successfully deployed. It's not executing on time. The program is usppose to post picture on a set time.

Below, I called it at 20:05 and 23:06 to test the time but it did not execute.

```
other functions
def main():
    #daily single post
    schedule.every().day.at("20:05").do(reddit_post_daily)

    # deleting the image after posting
    schedule.every().day.at("20:10").do(remove_pc)

    schedule.every().day.at("23:06").do(reddit_ps)

    # deleting the image after posting
    schedule.every().day.at("23:10").do(remove_p)

    #daily gallery post
    schedule.every().day.at("17:00").do(reddit_pr)

    # deleting the image after posting
    schedule.every().day.at("17:05").do(remove_g)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've tried different time zone, but it still does not work.